# Maximum number of people on an Account's Account Team

Tags: account-teams

We're looking at using Account Teams in our upcoming Salesforce restructure.

What I haven't been able to find is if there'a  maximum number of people that can be on the team for any given account.

Is there an upperbound for how large an Account Team can be? What's the max? If we had to, could we put all 200+ users as a member of a single account team?

Comment: This Trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sales-team-collaboration/sell-as-a-team includes the sentence "Salesforce Account Teams can include up to five people" so glad to see your question and the answer posted here...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tested this in a Sandbox with 1200 active users. I was able to add all users to the Account Team for a single account. This makes me suspect that there is no hard limit.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. There may be a hard limit, but I have far less than 1200 users. So it'll work for me!